# Attempting to construct a Pivot table-like item in SQL

Tags: select, count, ssms

I am trying to create a result that shows a breakdown of industries in an area. The end result will look something like this.

```
  Area          Industry                    Number of sites
 000000       All industries                        250
 000001       Industry 1(11 and 21)                 22
 000001       Industry 2(23)                        25
 ......
 000001       Industry 10 (81)                      120
```

Some background so that the above makes sense. In the original data set, there are 6 digit codes for the industry. We break them down based on the first two digits and then make custom groups. 11 and 21 are one group and so on. I can figure how to get individual rows of this but struggling to find out how to get all 11 rows in one result. I can write and execute 11 separate queries but am hoping to get it one result.  Below is the code for getting one of the rows. Is this the place for using a JOIN or UNION command or operator?

```
SELECT
[Area],
COUNT(*) AS [Number of Sites]
FROM
dbo.sizeclassreport
Where area='000001' and (code like '11%' or code like '21%')
GROUP BY
[area]
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was something simple but the internet results were confusing. All it is putting a "UNION ALL" between each query.

```
SELECT
[Area],
COUNT(*) AS [Number of Sites]
FROM
dbo.sizeclassreport
Where area='000001' and (code like '11%' or code like '21%')
GROUP BY
[area]
UNION ALL
SELECT
[Area],
COUNT(*) AS [Number of Sites]
FROM
dbo.sizeclassreport
Where area='000001' and (code like '23%')
GROUP BY
[area]
UNION ALL
SELECT
[Area],
COUNT(*) AS [Number of Sites]
FROM
dbo.sizeclassreport
Where area='000001' and (code like '31%' or code like '32%' or code like 
'33%')
GROUP BY
[area]
```